# Mobile browser not using correct responsive images

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, responsive

My responsive images are working correctly on desktop Chrome when I switch to mobile mode in dev utilities... however, when I actually look at the site on an s7, s5, s3, or iPhone (not sure which model my wife has), the wrong images are showing.

Here is a test page.

http://herschbachphotography.com/gallery_index/imagetest.html

The banner images are labeled Mobile, S, M, or L to verify which image is being used. The second vertical b&w image is labeled S, M, or L.

Here is the code for the images:

```
<img
            id="banner"
            src="../graphics/banner_19202.jpg"
            sizes=" (max-width: 480px) 480px,
                    (max-width: 1280px) 1280px,
                    (max-width: 1920px) 1920px,
                    (min-width: 1921px) 2560px,
                    100vw"
            srcset="../graphics/banner_4802.jpg 480w,
                    ../graphics/banner_12802.jpg 1280w,
                    ../graphics/banner_19202.jpg 1920w,
                    ../graphics/banner_25602.jpg 2560w"
            alt="Tim Herschbach Fine Art Photography"/>
```

and

```
<img
                    class="vertical"
                    src="../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_medium2.jpg"
                    sizes=" (max-width: 675px) 271px,
                            (max-width: 1920px) 620px,
                            (min-width: 1921px) 1240px,
                            100vw"
                    srcset="../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_small2.jpg 271w,
                            ../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_medium2.jpg 620w,
                            ../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_large2.jpg 1240w"
                    alt="Dove In Snow photograph"/>
```

Comment: Looks good to me... Can you maybe add what exactly means 'the wrong images are showing' ? Might give a clue.

Comment: In Chrome, the mobile images ("Mobile" and "S") are showing correctly. But on the phones I listed above, the "S" and "M" images are showing respectively, which is incorrect.